# How to animate with random values in Freestyle Lines

Tags: animation

I want to animate the Dashed line with random values. How to do it? Any methods?

Thank You

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The stroke and gap lengths can be keyframed. If you, for example, set keyframes at the beginning and end of the animation range, at value `1` for them all, then, in the graph editor, you can give their f-curves a *Noise* modifier:

[image]

I think you're still limited to a (spatially) repeating cycle of 3 dash-and-gap pairs, but it might still do?

[image]